# If statement in markup using interpolated API data

Tags: javascript, api, conditional-operator

I am using the OpenWeather API to gather weather data and display it. I am just using vanilla JavaScript. Depending on the type of weather, I want to display a special message. However, I am not sure how to do this using data gathered from an API when it is being interpolated.

Here is the variable with the markup that displays the data from the API.

```
    const markup = `
        <h2 class="city-name" data-name="${name},${sys.country}">
          <span>${name}</span>
          <sup>${sys.country}</sup>
        </h2>
        <div class="city-temp">${Math.round(main.temp)}<sup>°C</sup></div>
        <figure>
          <img class="city-icon" src="${icon}" alt="${
        weather[0]["description"]
      }">
          <figcaption>${weather[0]["description"]}</figcaption>
        </figure>
      `
```

I want to include special text based on what text is displayed by "description". For example, if it is "clear sky" it will display message A, "rainy" message B and so on.

I have it in a ternary operator, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
`${weather[0]["description"]}` == "clear sky" ? "<h4>Groovy</h4>" : "<h4>Nope</h4>";;
```

I tried just changing it to ["description"] or removing the backticks, but it still isn't working.

Comment: closing `}` in at the wrong position. It should be _after_ ternary operator ends: `\`${ weather[0]["description"] == "clear sky" ? "<h4>Groovy</h4>" : "<h4>Nope</h4>"  }\``

Comment: Backticks are not needed inside expression already wrapped in backticks (a template). Could you show what you've tried without them? And btw `;` is used to separate statements, and inside your template you deal with expressions, so you need to drop it.